# How to make short lines on X axis in R

Tags: r, plot, visualization

I'm trying a plot where I have small ticks on the X-axis. So instead of these long vertical lines I just want them on the X-axis like the example. Is there a function for this in R?

Example code:

```
x <- cos(seq(0,20,0.1))+rnorm(201,mean=0,sd=0.5)
lines <- seq(1,201,10)
plot(x)
abline(v=lines)
```

[image: Want it to look like this]

[image: Example picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `rug`

```
x <- cos(seq(0,20,0.1))+rnorm(201,mean=0,sd=0.5)
lines <- seq(1,201,10)
plot(x)
rug(lines)
```

[image]